# Is 2's complement representation also used on positive numbers?

Tags: c, integer, unsigned-integer

when i write :

```
signed int a = 4;
```

is my computer using 2's representation?

because if my computer use 2’s complement representation to represent number 4, this is what will happen on a 8 bit machine:

binary value of 4 : 0000 0100

2’s complement become: 1111 1011

add 1: 1111 1100

but i read that when the most signficant bit is 1 , your number is negative. but here my most significant bit is 1 and my number is 4 . it is not -4.

why my number 4 has a 1 as the most significant bit?

Comment: 2's complement is for subtraction; you don't use it to perform addition.

Comment: You might want to [read more about two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). Also what you call 2's complement (1111 1011) is not actually two's complement but [*one's* complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - just OP's poor phrasing as he then adds the `1`.

Comment: And two answer your question, two's complement is to represent negative numbers. Positive numbers are represented as is.

Comment: Your number *was* `4`, but by perfoming the 2's complement on `4` you made it `-4` in this notation, it does not remain the same number.

Answer (score 2):

> 2’s complement become: 1111 1011

No. Where did you get that idea from? 1111 1011 is `-5` in two's complement. `-5` is not `+4`.

`-4` is not the same as `+4` either.

The binary value of `4` is 0000 0100. The signed number variable representation of `4` is therefore also 0000 0100.

Two's complement is irrelevant unless the number is negative.

> why my number 4 has a 1 as the most significant bit?

It doesn't. Your `-4` has a 1 as the msb.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize a as :

```
signed int a;
```

The machine will keep the last bit(MSB) as a marker for positive or negative values.

0 for Positive

1 for Negative

When you take 2's complement of a number which is taking the 1's complement and adding 1 to it(regarding the confusion in the phrasing of the question)
you negate the number you are working with.

So when you do 2's complement of 4  you get 1111 1100 which is binary notation for -4
Since this is negative number you get the MSB as 1

Answer (score 0):

In some sense a signed integer is in "2's complement", in that it requires the left-most bit to be reserved for the sign. "2's complement" tells how to make a positive integer negative by using "flip the bits + one". The *implication* is that the positive integer is in base 2 and can use only n-1 bits, with n the number of bits in an int.

So "2's complement" is a way to represent negative numbers in binary, not positive numbers in binary.